# Why is MS Access Report repeating the details section?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access, report

I am using MS Access 2010, and I created a form that then produces a report.

Because it is designed to print on a label instead of a regular piece of paper, the entire report is smaller than usual, with the Report Header being .5" tall and the Details section being 1.5" tall. The label is 2" tall with no border/margin on the top or bottom. It will not let me set a page size when I click on the size button; instead, nothing happens.

When I go to Layout View, it shows the Report Header once at the top and then the Details section many times. This is a screenshot of a sample label:

[image: Label Problem]

I'm not sure exactly how many times it repeats, but it appears to be at least 100. Putting in page numbers shows that it thinks that the entire thing is one page, instead of being 100+ pages. I tried both forcing a line break and having it create a new row after the section, neither of which changed anything.

Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: What you've described is a bit difficult to follow. It sounds like the report is doing what it is supposed to, just not the way you want it to. Did you use the label wizard to set this up? Does it look correct in print preview?

Comment: I didn't use the label wizard, but instead made it from scratch. Nowhere in it did I put that it should print more than one copy of the details. In Print Preview, it looks correct if I only have it show one page. If I have it show multiple pages, the first is correct and the rest show the details section with no heading.

Comment: Maybe you should try the label wizard to see if it will format it the way you are looking for.

Comment: Perhaps the data you are using is repeating for some reason.  Try using a select unique query with only the data you need.